# Display specific number format (currency,units,...) depending on content of another field (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

On a report, I want to display numbers in a specific format (e.g. thousands, millions, billions; different currency or unit symbols) depending on a "number type" specified in a different column.
I found a working solution (below), but I wonder if there is a better way to implement this.

In Table1, each record contains a value and a number type:

```
NumberType      Value
---------------------------
GDP             12300000000
LiteracyRate    0.95
Population      15000000
```

Table 2 contains formatting information for each number type, such as currency and unit symbols:

```
NumberType    Prefix  Suffix  ScalingFactor
--------------------------------------------
GDP            $        
LiteracyRate           %       100
Population
```

The **desired output** looks like this:

```
NumberType     DisplayValue
-------------------------------
GDP            $ 12.3 Trillion
LiteracyRate   95 %
Population     15.0 Million
```

My **current solution** is to create an SQL query where I create a calculated field DisplayValue. In the calculated field I

- Concatenate the prefix and suffix specified in Table 2
- Multiply with the scaling factor
- Use multiple nested IIF statements to display numbers as thousands, millions, etc. For example `IIf([Value]>1000,round([Value]/1000,1)&" thousand",[Value])`

I find that the SQL statement gets quite hard to read, and I wonder if there is a more elegant and efficient implementation, maybe using formatting strings. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This smells like over-normalization to me.  By storing key-value pairs rather than normal fields, you're missing out on strong data typing.  If you're set on this structure, however, then I think you're on the right track.  As you say, there's probably a simpler way to handle the actual calculation with format strings, hopefully an Access expert can help with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you had another table:

```
Range   RangeName       LowValue    HighValue
Low                     1           999
Million     Million     1000000     9999999999
Thousand    Thousand    1000        99999
Trillion    Trillion    10000000000 9999999999999
```

Watch out for those high values, after a thousand, I get tangled up by US numbers!

You could say:

```
SELECT t1.NumberType, 
      [Prefix] & IIf(Nz([scalingfactor],0)>0,Val([value])*[scalingfactor],Val([Value]))/[lowvalue] & [suffix] & " " & [RangeName] AS DisplayValue
FROM t3, t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.NumberType = t2.NumberType
WHERE (((IIf(Nz([scalingfactor],0)>0,Val([value])*[scalingfactor],Val([Value]))) Between [lowvalue] And [highvalue]));
```

Giving a result:

```
NumberType      DisplayValue
Population      15 Million
GDP             $1.23 Trillion
LiteracyRate    95%
```

You can also do quite a lot with report controls as long as you remember to rename them. DlookUp for example. Reports also allow you to use VBA and your own functions.

Comment: on thing to look out for with this might be, if using `double`, there are a lot of numbers between 999 and 1000.

Comment: @Brad Good point, I did use double, but I was only thinking of percentages for the low end. I did not consider that there may be countries with GDP or Population <1000

Comment: True. Fractions of a percentage point are not too uncommon though. and GDP could have fractions of a dollar (even though that is pretty darn optimistic)